# Can a user click a login hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I can log a user out of my MVC Core application as follows:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
}
```

Identity server is called and the user is logged out as expected.  Is it possible to log a user in by specifying a link? I realise the user will be automatically forwarded if they access a secure area of the website.  However, is it possible for the user to say themselves that they wish to login (the return url would be the homepage i.e. home/Index).

I have spent the last hour researching this.  I have found lots of examples explaining how to logout explicitly, however I have not found an example, which shows how to login explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear, but if I understand you properly, you're looking for the `returnUrl` query param. For example, if you want to send a user to `/foo`, but you want them to login in first, you can create a link like:

```
<a href="/login?returnUrl=/foo">Go to Foo, but login first</a>
```

Comment: I am using identity server for authentication.  I see a 404 error when I try your idea.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really unclear, but I will try:

At your `Account` controller (which is the secure area, right?) create a secured "Login" action.

```cs
[Authorized] //actually you don't need this attribute here when have it on controller level
//All this action does is authenticating the user and redirecting to home/Index
public ActionResult AutoLogin()
{
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Then in your layout add:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
       "Login", "AutoLogin", "Account", routeValues: new{}, htmlAttributes: new {id = "loginLink"})
```